# Is there a method to simultaneously block-diagonalize a set of group matrices?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Assume that you are explicitly given the representation matrices of a group.
How does one go about finding that common basis which will find the irreducible components of all of them simultaneously?

---

Assume that you don't know the irreducibles or the branching rules of the group. I am looking for a down-to-earth linear algebraic way to find the similarity transformation which will do the decomposition with no knowledge of the group's representation theory.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/185001/448 . If someone reading this knows a better place to point people than my answers, please do so!

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Thanks! Isn't my case simpler than what that other question asks for? I am saying - lets say you have $8$ $4\times 4$ matrices given to you explicitly. Then what would you do?

Comment: Wait, is this a group in characteristic zero? Then I would compute the center of this group algebra (linear algebra) and diagonalize the central elements (since they commute).

Comment: Some old but rather explicit physics notes of mine on doing this in the context of a simple lattice gauge theory are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTBBePgIzD0a3ZGSWt3aFlJS00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I am working over complex numbers. So you say that I can just detect the centre of the group and diagonalize any one of them and this basis should simultaneously block-diagonalize the rest of the matrices? But finding the center is still a brute-force calculation - right?

Comment: In a given example if I find a similarity transformation which diagonalizes the center then that applied on everyone else doesn't produce the same block-diagonal structure. In an irreducible representation decomposition all the matrices should have the same block structure.

Comment: May be one has to go to the center and do this repearedly on each block to get the full reduction.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I checked with an example that the similarity transformation that diagonalzies the center does not give the most irreducible decomposition of the other elements of the group. How does one find that basis which will do that?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer And for the same set of matrices there seems to exist multiple different block diagonalizations.